# Subsonic Exception - The member 'TestMode' is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

i´m using LINQ with the subsonic in a class to get my data here is the code below:

```
public IQueryable<Veiculo> SelecionaVeiculosSite() 
        {
                   return (from v in _db.Veiculos
                            where v.Ativo == true &&
                            v.Marca.Ativo == true && 
                            v.Modelo.Ativo == true
                            select v
                           );            

        }
```

You will see one difference in line at "v.Marca.Ativo == true", I did one modification in template of ActiveRecord to get a Object and not a IQueryable.

This is the code modified in the template generated:

```
public Marca Marca
    {
        get
        {

              var repo=OKMMySql.Marca.GetRepo();
              return (from items in repo.GetAll()
                   where items.ID_Marca == _ID_Marca
                   select items).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

in the Code it´s ok, but this Select return this Execution time Error:

> The member 'TestMode' is not supported.

I did not founded nothing in the Net about this error.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, it's logged in the issue list on github and is being worked on at the moment. See the link below for details:

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/148

Comment: Thanks Adam i foud the solution in the link that you indicated. Was a problem in the Subsonic.Core